# Prove or disprove: There is a general sorting algorithm which can sort an array of length n in O(n) if it's min-heap-ordered

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, heap

> Prove or disprove: There is a general sorting algorithm which can sort
>   an array of length `n` in `O(n)` if the array is min-heap-ordered.

Tomorrow I write exam and very scared from proof task... Here is one I find from older exam and very hard for solve as expected... : /

I think I know answer but my reason isn't good. So my reason is the statement is false because when array is min-heap-ordered, let imagine it as a tree, then the leaves of the tree will not be sorted. And that array is sorted is required for sorting it in `O(n)`. For this reason statement is wrong..

Here I have example I make my own min-heap-ordered tree:

```
       1
      / \
     3   2
    / \   \
   8   99  7
```

From this we make array, we have `1, 3, 2, 8, 99, 7` You see this is no sorted at all but min-heap-ordered. No possible to sort this in `O(n)`.

---

Very sure my solve is wrong pls can you show me how you do it correct and very sorry for my English I try my best..

I think what my solve is miss, I need prove that min-heap-ordered have no sorted leaves? But how?

Comment: Your solution seems alright since you have successfully found a counter-example. However, I'm not very sure about that. Anyway, good luck tomorrow!

Comment: Theres an algorithm called [Heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort). Your question basically deals with the second step of that algorithm.

Comment: My intuition is this can be disproved by induction on the depth of the heap. Because you already need to spend order of n time merging two merged arrays, so it's impossible to be linear time overall. I think it's very analogous to merge sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is precisely correct. You can produce a formal proof *reductio ad absurdum* (reduction to a contradiction) by using the hypothetical sorting algorithm to produce a linear-time general sorting algorithm.

The linear-time algorithm to sort the array `A` consists of constructing a heap-ordered array by starting with an ordered sequence of integers less than `min(A)`, and then adding `A` at the end. The total length of this new array is `O(|A|)` -- with the standard array representation of a heap, you need the next larger power of 2 elements, which is at most `3·|A|`. You can then use the linear-time algorithm to sort a heap-ordered array to sort this new array, and finally remove the prepended sequence to produce the original array in sorted order.

Since that contradicts the well-known result that linear-time general sorting is impossible, we can conclude that there is no linear-time algorithm for sorting a heap-ordered array.

Answer (score 1):

The usual proof for this kind of problems is reducing some well-known problem to yours. That is, you show that if it possible to solve your problem in linear time then it is also possible to solve some problem X in linear time. But  it is known that X is not solvable in linear time, thus by contradiction your problem is not as well.

An excellent example of such problem X is sorting. It is well-known that it is impossible to sort N elements in `Omega(n log n)` time (Omega here is a proper way to deal with lower bounds, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)).

Now note that if we:

1. make a min-heap from N elements
2. sort N elements from min-heap order

then we effectively sort these elements from scratch. Thus either of these two steps takes at least `n log n` time. There exists an algorithm to perform the first step in linear time (it should likely be in your textbook), giving us the `Omega(n log n)` lower bound for the second step, Q.E.D.